# Bootstrap popover does not work - Even after copying working examples from other posts

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I have read through post after post on here, and still cannot get bootstrap popover to work in rails!

Here is the current code I am using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#myPopover').popover();
</script>
```

And the button:

```
<button type="button" id="myPopover" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" data-  placement="right" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus."   data-original-title="" title="">
  Popover on Right
</button>
```

Absolutely nothing I try will get the popover to appear though! The demo popovers on the bootstrap website do work however, so It cant be a problem with my browser...

Any tips?

Comment: How are you including Bootstrap?

Comment: if you are running the script before the document is ready it won'r work, try putting the script at the end of body or use document ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I finally have this working with both the js menu, and popover. It seems the popover needs the tooltip to be loaded first.

In `vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.js` I had to move the `//=require ./tooltip.js` above `//=require ./popover.js` This now works perfectly.

Thanks again for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

*Demo* http://jsfiddle.net/YHPNt/

The reason it is acting weird is coz you might be missing some script include.

take a look at this minimalistic demo, add this in your page and you should be sorted.

Hope this helps `:)`

**Script**

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>

  <script type='text/javascript' src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
```

**Code**

```
<p> TEst HULK </p>
<button type="button" id="myPopover" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="popover" data-  placement="right" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus."   data-original-title="" title="">
  Popover on Right
</button>
```

**JQ Code**

```
$('#myPopover').popover({
    trigger: 'hover',
        'placement': 'top'
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys!

It seems this was the missing line:

    <script type='text/javascript' src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitterbootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

I dont understand why it requires this for the js components... yet the rest of bootstrap works fine. As you suggested, I must be missing an include somewhere. 

Thanks for the help again!

Comment: Ok - not quite as fixed as I thought!

If I include that line, popovers work, but menu doesnt.

If I dont include that line, menu works, popovers dont!